# imports & pathnames on windows

Tags: python

newbie Python question, 2.7.2 on Windows XP

I saved a one-line hello.py file [print "hello there"] in the current directory.

At the command prompt I use import to run the command

```
 >>> import hello
 hello there
```

ok - that's fine.

But what do you type if hello.py were in a subfolder of the current directory called "tempFolder"?

Comment: add a file called `__init__.py` in the folder. Then `import tempFolder.hello`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is your directory structure:

```
currentdir
    /tempFolder
        hello.py
```

### Short Answer:

You should have a `__init__.py` in your directory of import.
So it should look like:

```
currentdir
    /tempFolder
        __init__.py
        hello.py
```

**Note**: the `__init__.py` could be *blank*. There is no harm in that.

Check the [official documentation](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#packages) for more information on this

Comment: ok thanks - that worked fine once I realized to type "import tempFolder.hello"

Answer (score 1):

The module is searched in Python's [module search path](http://docs.python.org/py3k/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path).

You have two solutions:

1. Make the folder `tempFolder` be a [python package](http://docs.python.org/py3k/tutorial/modules.html#packages): Add a file named `__init__.py` in the folder `tempFolder`
2. Add the folder `tempFolder` to the [PYTHONPATH](http://docs.python.org/py3k/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH)